# WinRT RichEditBox: Does not display textcolor if passing a RTF String?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, rtf, uwp

If I try to set a RTF String with some color parts in it, the RichEditBox won't show these colorized text parts. Some sample code:

```
rtfBox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, 
  @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang2055\deflangfe2055{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}" +
  @"{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;}" + 
  @"{\*\generator Riched20 6.2.9200}{\*\mmathPr\mnaryLim0\mdispDef1\mwrapIndent1440 }\viewkind4\uc1 " +
  @"\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang7 This Text is \cf1 red\cf0 , \i italic \i0 and \b bold\b0 .\par}");
```

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: I'm wondering if your `RichEditBox` has some default brush set that would override the one set with RTF. Have you tried playing with that? Setting `Foreground="{x:Null}"` or something of that sort?

Comment: I tried with a new empty project and also by setting `Foreground="{x:null}"` - no effect. Tried it even with different RTF strings and reseting whole style from generic.xaml!